# Retry tpl dataflow with/without Rx

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow, rx.net

I am using .net reactive extension with TPL dataflow. Here is my pipeline:

I am getting data points as stream from some external source and then I am transforming data points using dataflow TransformBlocks. After this I am using Rx buffer to buffer streamed points for 1 second and at last I am using dataflow Actionblock to post these buffered data points on REST end point.

I would like to retry REST post operation on transient errors. Where should I retry:

1. After buffer?
2. Inside Action block?
3. What would happen to continuous streaming at the time of retry? I don't want to miss any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going off the high level overview provided, I think it would be easiest to retry in the final `ActionBlock`. Your `ActionBlock` would post and confirm success before ending. Depending on the volume of data this approach lets you spool up as many `ActionBlock`s as necessary without too much concern over dropped items, really shouldn't be any. If a single or many `ActionBlock` instances fail their post, your items will still be streaming and distributed with respect to how you've set up your buffers and input queues waiting for their chance on the wire.

**Edit**
Just some pseudo code, but this will take a batch of datapoints, the IEnumerable, and try to post them five times. The bounded capacity will cause each instance of the handler to queue up 1000 batches and the parallelism will distribute the batches amongst the action blocks. Optionally an unbounded `Buffer` could be added before the `ActionBlock` to hold all incoming batches. You'll need to take care that your producer, the stream, doesn't greatly out run your consumer, REST service.

```
    public void ConfigureFinalActionBlock() {
        var dataPointBuffer = new BufferBlock<IEnumerable<Datapoint>>(new DataflowBlockOptions() {
            BoundedCapacity = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
        });

        var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
            BoundedCapacity = 1000,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
        };
        var restBlock = new ActionBlock<IEnumerable<Datapoint>>(async (data) => {
            var success = false;
            var attempts = 0;
            while (!success && attempts < 5) {
                attempts++;
                success = await MyApiPostAsync(data);
            }
        }, options);

        dataPointBuffer.LinkTo(restBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions() {
            PropagateCompletion = true
        });
```

Comment: Let's take this case. I received buffer of 100000 datapoints and I am retrying it in actionblock. In the next second only, again I'll receive another 100000 datapoints with actionblock post request. So I can miss some points.How to set multiple actionblocks with input queues.

Comment: How can you miss any points? Buffer has unlimited queue, new messages will either wait for the processed ones, or, if you state a max degree of parallelism, will execute concurrently in other thread.